# OpenGL and Java: Syntax highlighting

Tags: java, opengl

I am planning to create a Graphics (and possibly Physics, maybe Game) Engine just to see how things work on the lower level, and also because some concepts are hard to grasp on high-level C++.

Now I am wondering: How will I get OpenGL highlighting in for example Netbeans when programming Java, I am a little bit lost on that. Do I need to use a wrapper then? Is syntax highlighting even a necessity?

I don't want the wrapper to provide a lot of functionality though, as I want to build the graphics engine from scratch.

Anyone that has experience on this?

Comment: What syntax highlighting do you mean? Java or GLSL?

Comment: @noone The syntax of OpenGL itself. I'm actually already lost on how to communicate to the OpenGL driver from within Java itself.

Comment: @skiwi OpenGL isn't a language you will need to highlight the language you're using.

Comment: If you are using an OpenGL Library, like LWJGL, your "OpenGL-Code" is nothing more then Java-Code and therefore the default java highlighting is all you need.

Comment: @Korashen So LWJGL is a wrapper that purely routes the OpenGL function calls to the driver, right? If it does not provide more other things, then it sounds great for me. Only downside(?) is that when a new version of OpenGL appears you have to get a new version of the wrapper aswell, if new functionality is included.

Comment: LWJGL is more than just an OpenGL wrapper. If you want only OpenGL bindings, have a look at JOGL

Comment: @noone Ok thanks that was where I was looking for, and then of course the syntax highlighting is pure Java.